# Mistake naming the application's build number

Tags: ios, xcode, build, upload, standards

I just finished my first iOS application and I'm planning to release it on the Apple Store. However this is not my first build, previously I uploaded 2 different builds on TestFlight in order to testing.
As the title says, due to my ignorance about naming the build according to the standards I made a little mistake:

- The first released is named: Version 1.0 - Build 1.0
- The second released provided bug fix: Version 1.0 - **Build 2.0** (Instead of Build 1.0.1)

Now I have to upload my final version which will be sent to the Apple Store Review. How should I name this build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build number you set in Xcode actually changes a value in your apps info plist. The key is **CFBundleVersion** and its value is a **string**. You can change it to any value you haven't yet uploaded to iTunesConnect. Just make sure you know which value represents which build and you should be fine.

You could for example change the build to **2.0a** or **2.0.1** or if you wish rectify your mishap and make it **1.0.1** - what's important is that you don't use a build value that you've already uploaded and you make it a value that you can remember which build it represents.